# C++ popen function hangs

Tags: c++, popen

I'm working on an embedded system which runs linux kernel 3.14 on a powerPC device.
I need to run a C++ application that should launch a system command and retrieve the result.
I tried with *popen* but it hangs. Look the code below:

```
#define PATH_MAX_MIO 255

...

FILE *fp;
char path[PATH_MAX_MIO];

fp = popen("ll", "r"); // It hangs here. "ll" is the linux command to view files inside a directory
if (fp == NULL){ return; }


while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX_MIO, fp) != NULL)
    std::cout<< path;

pclose(fp);
```

With a debugger I can run till popen call, than it hangs and if I launch command *top* I can see the process occupies almost all CPU (change between 90% and 99.9%).

I can't figure out why it happens.
Any advice?
Thank you.

**.: EDIT :.**
This is the output of `strace -f` command

```
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5348] <... select resumed> )      = 15 (in [14], left {0, 0})
[pid  5348] select(15, [], NULL, NULL, {0, 0} <unfinished ...>
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5348] <... select resumed> )      = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[pid  5348] --- SIGPROF {si_signo=SIGPROF, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=14594, ptr=0x3902}} ---
[pid  5348] sigreturn() (mask [])       = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  5347] --- SIGPROF {si_signo=SIGPROF, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=14594, ptr=0x3902}} ---
[pid  5347] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> [], 8) = 27
[pid  5347] syscall_671098914(0, 0x1, 0xba4bdeda, 0xcbcb28a, 0xb6f76f8c, 0xb6f76f20) = 0
[pid  5348] select(15, [14], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  5348] select(15, [14], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  5347] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  5347] --- SIGPROF {si_signo=SIGPROF, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=14594, ptr=0x3902}} ---
[pid  5347] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> [], 8) = 27
[pid  5347] syscall_268774496(0, 0x10052a5c, 0x28002824, 0xb7a2f008, 0x1, 0xb7a379c0) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5348] select(15, [14], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  5348] select(15, [14], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  5347] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  5347] --- SIGPROF {si_signo=SIGPROF, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=14594, ptr=0x3902}} ---
[pid  5347] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> [], 8) = 27
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid  5347] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
```

Ted Lyngmo suggested to launch the trace which only show the exec* operations, the result is this one:

```
strace -f ../runtime/Run6 2>&1 | grep -E 'exec[a-z]+\('
execve("../runtime/Run6", ["../runtime/Run6"], [/* 13 vars */]) = 0
[pid  1068] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "cat /proc/version"], [/* 13 vars */]) = 0
[pid  1069] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/proc/version"], [/* 13 vars */]) = 0
```

Then it hangs again

Comment: What's `ll`? What's `PATH_MAX_MIO`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: "ll" is the linux command that shows the list of files inside a directory. PATH_MAX_MIO define the array's length.

Comment: `ll` is often an [alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137703/difference-between-ls-l-and-ll).  Try `/usr/bin/ls` instead.

Comment: @PaulSanders I just tried, same result. It still hangs.

Comment: "ll" is not really a linux command, it's often an alias to `ls -alF` or some such. `popen` may or may not run an alias.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/EwNWcu). Your system might be broken. Can you execute `/bin/sh -c /bin/ls` in a terminal?

Comment: @PaulSanders `ls` should be in `/bin` not in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: it is probably useless to indicate the path of _ls_, just do `ls -l` without its path

Comment: @nm Yes, sorry.

Comment: @bruno `ls` can be an alias too

Comment: I tried with "/bin/sh -c /bin/ls". It works in a shell but not in popen

Comment: @PaulSanders you prefer `\ls` ?

Comment: Can you `strace` your program to see where it gets stuck? Also, if you run the program @n.m. linked to exactly as it is, does that also get stuck?

Comment: @TedLyngmo the program posted by n.m. behave in the same way. I tried with strace but it generates A LOT of lines, I need to find out what we are looking for

Comment: If the output from `strace` doesn't stop it's probably repeating a chunk of lines over and over again. Can you identify such a repeating chunk and include that in the question? It could give some hints. If it *does* stop (which still showing a high processor load), try `strace -f`.

Comment: The 'strace' command hangs with the process, instead 'strace -f' generates an output. I put it in the question

Comment: That looks odd. What does `strace -f program 2>&1 | grep -P 'exec[a-z]+\('` show? The `2>&1` assumes you are using a `/bin/sh`-like shell. Use `|&` if you are using a `/bin/csh`-like shell.

Comment: The option -P is not valid, I tried with -E and the result is this one:
`strace -f ../runtime/Run6 2>&1 | grep -E 'exec[a-z]+\('
execve("../runtime/Run6", ["../runtime/Run6"], [/* 13 vars */]) = 0
[pid  1068] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "cat /proc/version"], [/* 13 vars */]) = 0
[pid  1069] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "/proc/version"], [/* 13 vars */]) = 0`
Then it hangs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188341/discussion-between-ted-lyngmo-and-max-markson).

Comment: `popen` implementation in your standard library might be broken, try the hard way with fork/exec/dup.

Comment: @MaxMarkson Did you figure it out? I didn't hear back from you in the chat.

Comment: Yes, sorry. We had issues on other stuffs and I haven't tried your suggestion yet. I think I will be able to try in the afternoon